# MutableList(5) snippet in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, mutablelist

I have a problem with this snippet

```
fun main() {
    val list = MutableList(5)
    {
        4
    }
    println(list) 
}
```

[this snippet](https://pl.kotl.in/UelOEOTdS?theme=darcula) will print `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`

and

```
fun main() {
    val list = MutableList(5)
    {
        index -> 4 + index
    }
    println(list) 
}
```

[this snippet](https://pl.kotl.in/cs9XXKDW-?theme=darcula) will print [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

What i want to ask, and this is might be very very silly. If we using the same snippet as above, is there a way to make a custom list such as `[4, 6, 7, 9, 10]`

I try to use `[4, 6, 7, 9, 10]` or `(4, 6, 7, 9, 10)` or `4, 6, 7, 9, 10` or `4; 6; 7; 9; 10`, it just doesn't work.

If I used `4; 6; 7; 9; 10`, the list will print

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

if anyone care to help, [this snippet](https://pl.kotl.in/2f47xTqsJ?theme=darcula) below it just doesn't work

```
fun main() {
    val list = MutableList(5)
    {
        //[4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
        //(4, 6, 7, 9, 10)
        //4, 6, 7, 9, 10
        4; 6; 7; 9; 10
    }
    println(list) 
}
```

Comment: How about `val list = mutableListOf(4, 6, 7, 9, 10)`? Why are you fixated on using the `MutableList` constructor?

Comment: what you are saying is correct, it just I didn't know how to use `MutableList` and ask this silly question on how to make it work using `MutableList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've had a couple of answers telling you how to explicitly define a list with `listOf`/`mutableListOf`, and you've replied to them with a link (I can't access it) and asking about reading from standard input. I'm *assuming* that means your question hasn't been answered and you're trying to clarify what you're asking about, so I'll explain what's happening in the code in your replies, in case it helps clear things up.

```
// on each line single numbers from 1 to 5
val numbers = MutableList(5) { readln().toInt() } 
println(numbers) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`MutableList(5) { //some function }` is a list builder function ([documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html)) - the first parameter is the size of the list you want to generate.

The second parameter is the function that gets called to generate each item. It has a single parameter (as usual, called `it` unless you rename it) which contains the *index* of the item being generated. You can use this to generate values according to their position in the list, e.g. `(it * 2) + 1` for a list of odd numbers.

---

But you don't have to use that *index* value - you can produce a static value for each item, or pull data from anywhere you like to provide values. That's what `readln()` is doing - every time the function runs to generate one of the five items, it reads a line from standard input. You could also pull the next item from an `Iterator`, read a value from a `Random` generator, request something from an API - whatever you want. All that matters is that a value is returned, so the code in your function acts as an expression and returns a value to be used as the item in the list.

So if you really wanted to, you could do this:

```
// using an iterator because it has state, i.e. it remembers where it's up to in the list
val stuff = listOf("1", "4", "6", "7", "2").iterator()

fun main() {
   val myList = List(5) { stuff.next().toInt() }
   println(myList)
}
```

It's functionally the same as reading from standard input, it's just it polls the `stuff` *iterator* for values instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a mutable list with just `4, 6, 7, 9, 10` in it, the most direct way would be to create it with `mutableListOf`:

```
val list = mutableListOf(4, 6, 7, 9, 10)
```

This creates a size 5 `MutableList` with 4, 6, 7, 9, 10 as its values. No real need to use the indexed lambda construct to create this unless you have some kind of calculation to make, or all elements are the same.

Comment: From the theory [Please see Reading list from input](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/14879)  

`val numbers = MutableList(5) { readln().toInt() } // on each line single numbers from 1 to 5`  
`println(numbers) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  

Meaning if the user enter on each line single numbers from 1 to 5, it will print the output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  

But, why can't we do that by providing the value manually (just like using `val list = mutableListOf(4, 6, 7, 9, 10)`)not waiting from the standard input? or can we? It just that I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at that sequence of numbers: `4, 6, 7, 9, 10`

You can see that between the first and second value there is a delta of 2. Between the second and third value there's a delta of 1. Then there's a delta of 2 again, and so forth.

You can create such a list with:

```
val list = MutableList(5)
{
    index -> 4 + index + (index and 1) + (index / 2)
}
```

Which will generate

```
4 + 0 + (0 and 1) + (0 / 2) == 4 + 0 + 0 + 0 == 4
4 + 1 + (1 and 1) + (1 / 2) == 4 + 1 + 1 + 0 == 6
4 + 2 + (2 and 1) + (2 / 2) == 4 + 2 + 0 + 1 == 7
... etc ...
```

Comment: Can I ask you something?

From the theory [basic links](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/14879)

`val numbers = MutableList(5) { readln().toInt() } // on each line single numbers from 1 to 5
println(numbers) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Meaning if the user enter on each line single numbers from 1 to 5, it will print the output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

But, why can't we do that by providing the value manually not waiting from the standard input? or can we? It just that I didn't know how to do it.